# Order is not being filled

Tags: stocks

I placed a limit order bidding $0.10 higher than asking price. And despite that ask price is getting lower, my position is not filled. Please explain why does it happen?

---

It has happened to days in a row (yesterday and today) It was PFE stock, which I was able to buy only around 9:50 am. The order was only for 100 shares.

Comment: Are you trying to buy more shares than are available at the ask price you've noted? Is your data outdated?  More details on the underlying would help.

Comment: Also, did you place an out of hours order during trading hours (or vice versa)?

Comment: Please tell us the stock, and the date and time that you placed your order.

Comment: the stock is PFE, today the same story happened to me. The order was filled only at 9:50 am.

Comment: I filled the order at 8:32. I am subscribed for all necessary market data and use TWS for trading.

Comment: @EugeneEvgeny We need time zones for these times.  The New York Stock Exchange does not open until 9:30 am eastern time so no regular hours order would be filled before then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an accurate answer, you need to provide the number of shares in your order, the price that you were trying to buy them at as well as the Eastern Standard Time that you placed your order and the price and time that your order was filled.

PFE is a liquid stock and if you are trading at the market, you will easily get filled.

PFE opened at $41.82 x $41.85 and it briefly rose to about $42.22.  The only reason that a buy order would not fill during that time was if your buy price was lower.

PFE dropped under to a low price of $41.44 by 9:47 AM EST.

If you're not getting filled for orders placed at market prices then you need to verify that you're placing your order correctly.